# Go HTTP server: error reading preface from client

Tags: go, https, http2

My Go HTTP Server generates a lot of http2 errors per second:

```
2022/11/20 13:41:51 http2: server: error reading preface from client AAA:56990: read tcp XXX:8084->AAA:56990: i/o timeout
2022/11/20 13:41:51 http2: server: error reading preface from client BBB:27287: read tcp XXX:8084->BBB:27287: i/o timeout
2022/11/20 13:41:51 http2: server: error reading preface from client CCC:47260: read tcp XXX:8084->CCC:47261: i/o timeout
```

If I understand it right, the clients (`AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`) are misbehaving, and don't implement HTTP2 properly.

My questions:

1. Is it normal, or maybe I have some misconfiguration/bug in my server, that causes the problem?
2. If it is normal, is it possible to somehow help these clients, or they should be perceived as broken, and just ignored?
3. If it is normal, how can I suppress only these error messages, but keep others?

Comment: Any publicly visible server will get misbehaving, malicious, or broken client connections. If you don't have any control over `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC`, all you can really do is ignore them. If some are more troublesome and persistent, you can setup various network filters or application firewalls, but that is outside the scope of your Go http server configuration.

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/?search=http2 for some more information on client availability.